# NPM Scripts - Where to save custom script for local project?

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

I have an angular project where I am trying to create a custom script for the project and it is my first time working with scripts. I'm having trouble executing the script. I get the following error:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'patch' ]
2 info using npm@6.10.0
3 info using node@v10.10.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prepatch', 'patch', 'postpatch' ]
5 info lifecycle myapp@4.0.211~prepatch: myapp@4.0.211
6 info lifecycle myapp@4.0.211~patch: myapp@4.0.211
7 verbose lifecycle myapp@4.0.211~patch: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle myapp@4.0.211~patch: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/$
9 verbose lifecycle myapp@4.0.211~patch: CWD: /Users/core/www/myapp-client
10 silly lifecycle myapp@4.0.211~patch: Args: [ '-c', 'ngsw-patch.js' ]
11 info lifecycle myapp@4.0.211~patch: Failed to exec patch script
12 verbose stack Error: myapp@4.0.211 patch: `ngsw-patch.js`
12 verbose stack spawn ENOENT
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:48:18)
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
12 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
12 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
13 verbose pkgid myapp@4.0.211
14 verbose cwd /Users/core/www/ourmgmt-client
15 verbose Darwin 18.7.0
16 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "patch"
17 verbose node v10.10.0
18 verbose npm  v6.10.0
19 error file sh
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno ENOENT
22 error syscall spawn
23 error myapp@4.0.211 patch: `ngsw-patch.js`
23 error spawn ENOENT
24 error Failed at the myapp@4.0.211 patch script.
24 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

So far I am only testing a simple script which is:

```
console.log("Hello World");
```

Therefore I am guessing the error is to do with the script location. 
Currently I have it saved in the same location as my package.json file. **Is this the correct location?** Am I referencing it incorrectly (see below)?
If not where am I meant to store the custom script? Thanks in advance.

Here is my package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "patch": "ngsw-patch.js"
  }
```

Comment: Best practive would be to place your script under "scripts" folder. And the reason why your script don't run is because you need to execute the js, with node js for example.

node ngsw-patch.js

Comment: Thanks mate added node and worked. And noted on the scripts folder. If you would like to add it as answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I explained on my comment, best practice would be to place your script under "scripts" folder.

And the reason why your script don't run is because you need to execute the js.

NodeJS is a tool that can achieve this purpose.

So your script section would look like

```
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e",
"patch": "node ngsw-patch.js"
```

}

Than call simply with

```
npm run patch
```

or with the very great tool "yarn"